# Styling identically-named CSS classes differently based on count

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given a series of user generated lists in the following format:

```css
.birds {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="animals">
  <div class="elephants">
    elephants
  </div>
  <div class="cats">
    cats
  </div>
  <div class="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
  <div class="elephants">
    elephants
  </div>
  <div class="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
  <div class="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
  <div class="cats">
    cats
  </div>
  <div class="dogs">
    dogs
  </div>
  <div class="birds">
    Birds
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to style each instance of class "birds" so that each one gets a different shade of background-color blue (e.g. light blue, medium blue, dark blue), based on how many class "birds" are in the list, getting darker if more are present ?  Note that I will only have access to CSS, not HTML or Javascript.

Comment: No sure, but you may some answer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: If you're talking about an infinitely long gradation from say light blue to darkblue, which is always as smooth as can be based on how many `.birds` are there, then you cannot do it alone with CSS, you would need some flavor of javascript. If, however, you just want the first say 5 to have a nice gradient, and the ones after that to just stay the same color as the 5th one, then CSS should be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.birds { color: white; }

.birds                   { background-color: lightblue; }
.birds ~ .birds          { background-color: blue;      }
.birds ~ .birds ~ .birds { background-color: darkblue;  }
```

```html
<div class="animals">
  <div class="elephants"> elephants </div>
  <div class="cats">      cats      </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="elephants"> elephants </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="cats">      cats      </div>
  <div class="dogs">      dogs      </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, thanks for your snippet. This is a new method for me

Comment: probly the best resoultion w/o javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You also can try some of this:

```css
.animals{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue, blue);
}
.animals > div:not(.birds){
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="animals">
  <div class="elephants"> elephants </div>
  <div class="cats">      cats      </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="elephants"> elephants </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
  <div class="cats">      cats      </div>
  <div class="dogs">      dogs      </div>
  <div class="birds">     Birds     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice indeed.